# How to get PHPUnit to return the exact value I specify?

Tags: php, phpunit

The current test I'm writing will not for whatever reason return an object with a populated member. I have code that looks like this:

```
$testObject = new TestObject();
$testObject->id = 1;

$storerMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Storer::class)
    ->setMethods(['get'])
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$storerMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('get')
    ->willReturn($testObject);
```

When I take a look at `$testObject` in the code being called, I see something like this:

```
Mock_TestObject_28868d4d (10) (
    public 'id' -> null
    ...
)
```

How can I get `willReturn()` to return the original object I told it to return, or at least get a mocked version with the `id` member set?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that code should work. It does in the similar example I've just made, at least - the object returned from the mock's method is the exact same instance as `$testObject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the responses. It was an issue of mocking the wrong object. PHPUnit (in conjunction with PHP7) will automatically return a mocked object if the return type is set. In this case, the method signature

```
public function get(int $id): TestObject {
```

was working correctly. However, instead of mocking `TestObject` I was actually mocking `TestObject2` :( Thus, when trying to set the return value everything was working behind the scenes, but when expecting the `TestObject` return value, it wasn't working because I hadn't put it on the correct mock object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the whole point of that code is to generate code that has the same list of names and methods, but doesn't have the same class, so one can do DuckTyping.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use `returnValue` function:

```
$storerMock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValue($testObject);
```